# javascript Replacing \n with <br> inside createTextNode

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, createtextnode

I have a String with `\n` - line breaks in Javascript, that I want to replace for another text using `createTextNode()` in Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeText() {

var Explanation="Test\n Test2";

var parent3 = document.getElementById("The_Explanation"); 
parent3.innerHTML='';  
var myP3 = document.createElement("p");
var myText3 = document.createTextNode(""+Explanation);
myP3.appendChild(myText3);
parent3.appendChild(myP3);
}
</script>
```

All tries to get the line break into the new text failed so far. All functions that replace `\n` to `<br>` only bring me to the result

```
"Test<br> Test2"
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't put an element node inside a text node. Text nodes cannot have child nodes.

1. Split your string on new lines
2. Loop over the array and generate a text node for each part
3. Use `createElement('br')` to create a line break to go between each text node
4. append all of the above

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace for that:

```
   Explanation.replace( /\n/g, "<br />" )l
```

Comment: Here you don't need to escape '\'